# INSERT - EXEC problem. Empty output from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, exec

I need to `SELECT` specific data from stored procedure output so I am trying to insert the stored procedure's output into a table. I am very newbie in SQL.

So here is the code:

```
Declare @result table
(
    row_id int,
    quarry nvarchar(400),
    interval nvarchar(100),
    vskr_plan decimal(30,1),
    vskr_fact decimal(30,1),
    vskr_diff decimal(30,1),
    ruda_plan decimal(30,1),
    ruda_fact decimal(30,1),
    ruda_diff decimal(30,1),
    gpr_plan decimal(30,1),
    gpr_fact decimal(30,1),
    gpr_diff decimal(30,1),
    gm_plan decimal(30,1),
    gm_fact decimal(30,1),
    gm_diff decimal(30,1)
)

INSERT INTO @result
    EXEC [report].[DISP_KPI_QUARRY] @datet = N'2018-10-11'

SELECT * 
FROM @result
```

I have no errors with this code but it returns an empty table!

However if I execute:

```
EXEC [report].[DISP_KPI_QUARRY] @datet = N'2018-10-11'
```

I see all the data.

What is my mistake, guys?

Comment: Maybe your stored procedure does not return table and only has a select inside it, in this case when you exec it, it shows you the results but in won't insert them into your @result table

Comment: The SP output has exact the same structure as @result table.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to include your columns in `INSERT` statement in the same order as they are returned from your stored procedure. When you insert results from stored procedure, you need to be sure, that the count, datatype and order of the columns, that stored procedure returns match your `@result` table definition.

```
DECLARE @result table
(
    row_id int,
    quarry nvarchar(400),
    interval nvarchar(100),
    vskr_plan decimal(30,1),
    vskr_fact decimal(30,1),
    vskr_diff decimal(30,1),
    ruda_plan decimal(30,1),
    ruda_fact decimal(30,1),
    ruda_diff decimal(30,1),
    gpr_plan decimal(30,1),
    gpr_fact decimal(30,1),
    gpr_diff decimal(30,1),
    gm_plan decimal(30,1),
    gm_fact decimal(30,1),
    gm_diff decimal(30,1)
)

INSERT INTO @result (row_id, quarry, interval, vskr_plan, vskr_fact, vskr_diff, ruda_plan, ruda_fact, ruda_diff, gpr_plan, gpr_fact, gpr_diff, gm_plan, gm_fact, gm_diff)
EXEC [report].[DISP_KPI_QUARRY] @datet = N'2018-10-11'

SELECT *
FROM @result
```

Comment: Thank you but I still get the same result - empty table with named columns.

Comment: The only difference between SP output table structure and the table I want to insert the output to is: 

In SP first table  column declared as:

 row_id int identity(1,1)

And in my table first column declared as:

 row_id int

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин OK, Can you make (just for this test) additional error check with: BEGIN TRY INSERT ... EXEC ... END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE(); END CATCH. Are there any error messages? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like SP is not executed. If I execute SP itself it takes about 10 sec to complete BUT when I use INSERT EXEC - I am getting empty result in 1 sec.